# вопрос про фреймворки

Tags: фреймворк

здравствуйте, увлекаюсь разбработкой сайтов на протяжении 4х лет, последнее время всё чаще слышу про всякие фреймворки на подобии angular/laravel и пр. и сложился такой вопрос, на каком этапе развития сайта стоит их использовать? и стоит ли использовать вообще? в чём преимущество этих фреймворков, и можно ли обойтись без них? а так же используют ли их крупные компании на своих сайтах?

Comment: Николай, перед Вами скоро откроется прекрасный новый мир)

Answer (score 6):

Николай, Вы затронули крайне интересную тему.

### **Используют ли крупные компании фреймворки на своих сайтах?**

**Безусловно!** И не побоюсь сказать что как-раз таки крупные компании, у которых есть средства для разработки и понимание того, что им нужно, чаще используют фреймворки, нежели готовые решения.

Примеры:

- сервис BlaBlaCar разработан на Symfony (php)
- citilink разработан на Symfony (php)
- компоненты Symfony (php) используют и в других программных продуктах Laravel, Drupal, phpBB и.
- сайты сети RT(Russia Today) разработаны на Yii (php)...нужно признать - достаточно популярные СМИ и высоконагруженные проекты.
- сервисы Blizzard'а имеют в качестве основы Spring (Java)
- strana.ru, МТРК «МИР» (http://mirtv.ru/) разработаны на Spring (Java)
- сайт ТНТ, dom2.ru и все остальные веб-проекты ГАЗПРОМ-Медиа  разработаны на Spring (Java)
- hh.ru насколько я понимаю тоже вертится на Spring'e (Java)
- на Ruby on Rails был целый бум стартапов: Twitter, Groupon и все его клоны, Github
- многочисленные сервисы Google используют свои фреймворки angular и polymer.

И это только вершина айсберга...перечислять можно бесконечно (я называл те, которые сразу приходили на ум), просто ткните в вакансии разработчика любой интересующей компании и Вы увидите с какими фреймворками они работают.

*(кто знает другие примеры - пишите в комментарии и извините если не назвал Ваш любимый фреймворк или не упомянул вообще Ваш любимый ЯП)*

Надеюсь этот вопрос мы закрыли.

---

### Можно ли обойтись без них?

Теоритически можно и без света в пещере жить, но не многие выбирают данный путь.
Можно и написать с нуля...чисто теоритически.
Но чаще всего это неоправданно.

Зачем всё начинать с нуля если за тебя уже разработали огромное количество готовых каркасов на любой вкус и цвет?.. Более того чаще всего самописные каркасы будут гораздо хуже качеством. Дело тут не только в том, что над данными фреймворками работают профессионалы с огромным опытом, но и в том что в них УЖЕ вложены сотни тысяч человеко-часов работы и у Вас таких ресурсов(временных в первую очередь) не будет. У популярных фреймворков есть огромные коммьюнити, которые развивают свои фреймворки. У Вас всего этого скорее всего не будет.

Поэтому большинство разработчиков выбирают наиболее подходящий им фреймворк и работают с ним.

**Снизим обороты.**

Если снизить требования к продуктам, то безусловно можно обойтись и без фреймворков.

Например, Вам нужен блог...самый обычный и простой.
Можно конечно очень быстро запилить его на любом доступном фреймворке, но ещё быстрее будет поставить Wordpress.

Собственно, тут мы приходим к самой главной мысли:

***Мы используем ту или иную технологию исходя из того решает она наши задачи или нет.***

---

### В чём преимущество этих фреймворков?

Первые два вопроса, которые возникают, услышав данный вопрос:

- "этих" это каких?
- перед чем?

Я постараюсь для начала копнуть чуть глубже и опередить Ваш вопрос, а потом уже поясню для чего я это сделал.

По-моему мнению разные программные продукты расчитаны на разных потребителей и решают разные задачи.

**Есть продукты, которые предоставляют готовые решения**

Один из примеров я уже называл - это Wordpress. Вы можете его поставить, настроить и он будет полностью готов к работе.

В качестве других примеров можно назвать огромное количество сервисов на подобии Ucoz'а, Народа, Базиума, Wix'а и многих других конструкторов сайтов.

И некоторые могут иметь возможности для расширения функционала(Wordpress), но большинство же имеют ограниченный функционал и не имеют вообще или же имеют крайне небольшие возможности для расширения.

**Есть продукты, которые расчитаны на веб-мастеров и активную кастомизацию.**

Это многочисленные CMS (Битрикс, Joomla, OpenCart, NetCat, UMI.CMS), которые предоставляют доступ к своему исходному коду и некоторые инструменты для кастомизации своего функционала.

Здесь Вы уже можете кастомизировать и добавлять модели данных, используемых
на сайте, создавать собственные компоненты и модули.

И некоторым кажется, что вот она - свобода и лучше ничего и быть не может и в этот момент в игру вступают Фреймворки.

**Фреймворки - это программные продукты, ориентированные на разработчиков.**

Именно разработчиков! Не веб-мастеров!

Это каркасы приложений и платформы облегчающие разработку приложений и ускоряющие процесс разработки.

Продукты, ориентирующиеся на веб-мастеров, ограничены в возможностях собственной аудиторией. Чем сложнее они предоставят продукт, тем выше будет порог вхождения и тем меньшую аудиторию он охватит. И как правило чем гибче продукт, чем больше возможностей модификации в нём есть, тем сложнее он становится. Они стараются найти компромисс между сложностью, гибкостью продукта и его возможностьями. Но как правило большинство таких продуктов решает вопрос возможностей количеством готовых компонентов и модулей(ведь именно это нужно заказчику), при этом оставляя достаточно простые инструменты для разработчика. И раз уж мы затронули эту тему, то бизнес решает. А бизнесу нужны гарантии и время, поэтому упор делается на готовые компоненты и модули, которыми уже можно пользоваться, а не тем что в теории ещё можно разработать на данной системе.

Фреймворки же не скованы всеми этими обязательствами. Им не нужно запихнуть как можно больше модулей с новостями, медиабиблиотеками, корзиночками, катологами и прочим. В них этого нет! Им не нужно оглядываться на заказчиков, потому что как правило, все они бесплатны. Им не нужно оглядываться на новичков в разработке, потому, что они на них не расчитаны. Первыми же "клиентами" разработчиков фреймворков являются они же сами. Это продукты сделанные разработчиками, для разработчиков. Это продукты сделанные для себя в первую очередь!

Фреймворки созданы для того чтобы упростить жизнь разработчиков - и они это делают!

В то время как CMS в основном предоставляют готовые модули, решения и компоненты, фреймворки предоставляют каркас для приложения и инструменты для дальнейшей разработки.

И как правило эти инструменты очень гибкие и мощные.

Если CMS - это гараж в котором есть молотки, отвертки, саморезы и пилы, то фреймворк - это огромный цех со всеми возможными инструментами и расходными материалами, которые когда-либо только могут понадобится и с огромным количеством станков на все случаи жизни.

В фреймворках как правило есть мошнейшие инструменты для работы с данными и мошнейшие инструменты по кодогенерации.

Благодаря всему этому Вы можете за буквально пару минут создать с нуля любую модель данных вместе с контроллерами для их редактирования, просмотра, пагинации, поиска и фильтрации...За пару минут, в считанное количество кликов у вас будет готовый раздел администрирования к примеру новой модели данных.

И наверное, на этом мне стоит закругляться, потому что на данный вопрос, я по-моему уже ответил.

Подытожу: **Преимущество фреймворков в их возможностях!**

---

### Стоит ли вообще использовать фреймворки?

А это уже исключительно Ваше решение.

Вы можете специализироваться на разработке сайтов на Битриксе,Вордпрессе,Джумле и Вас может это вполне нравится. И никто не вправе каким бы то ни было образом оценивать Ваш выбор.

Многие разработчики переходят на фреймворки в процессе развития, потому что системы с которыми они работают перестают удовлетворять их в плане возможностей и потому что они сталкиваются с более сложными задачами.

Другая не менее значительная часть разработчиков, просто приходит на работу, на которой используют тот или иной фреймворк и им приходится на них перейти, однако, как правило они понимают преимущество в их использовании, в противном случае они не долго продержаться на этом месте работы.

На самом деле важная часть, поскольку со временем наши требования к качеству жизни повышаются и соответственно повышаются и наши зарплатные ожидания и рано или поздно нам приходится устроиться в команду, которая работает с тем или иным фреймворком.

В общем так или иначе в процессе развития все сталкиваются с переходом на фреймворки и я пока ещё не видел людей вернувшихся обратно. (не беру в расчёт тех людей, которые не осилили этот переход)

....

Однако если на этот вопрос смотреть с точки зрения конкретного проекта, тот тут нужно смотреть на предоставляемые возможности.

Если какой-то готовый продукт предоставляет абсолютно всё, ровно в том виде, котором нам надо из коробки, то проще использовать его.

Если же нам придётся это продукт кастомизировать, то нужно оценить, не будет ли дешевле разработать с нуля этот же функционал на фреймворке, чем пытаться кастомизировать уже готовый продукт.

Для неподготовленного слушателя, это может показаться странным, но такие случаи возникают гораздо чаще, чем Вы могли бы подумать.

Пользуясь уже используемой аллегорией скажу:

Гораздо проще в оборудованном цеху сделать с нуля стол, чем в гараже с гвоздями , стамеской и молотком пытаться сделать из стула - стол.

К данному сравнению напомню Вам о примере создания новой модели данных, с редактированием, просмотром, пагинацией поиском и фильтрацией за считанные минуты.

---

### На каком этапе развития сайта стоит их использовать?

Опять же первопричиной является не срок работы сайта а его возможности и потребности.

Чаще всего ещё на моменте проектирования сайта Вы понимаете, что для того чтобы реализовать все возможности Вашего ресурса, Вам необходимо его реализовывать на фреймворке.

Если же проект имеет длительную историю и постепенно развивается, то начинать переходить на фреймворк Вам стоит ровно в тот момент, когда Вы понимаете что Вам не хватает возможностей используемой Вами системой. И когда понимаете, что из-за отсутствия вменяемых инструментов, Вы тратите в разы больше времени для реализации того-же функционала.

Но не стоит быть эгоистом. Если Вы понимаете, что на данном месте работы специалисту для поддержки ресурса платят условно 40 т.р., не стоит там внедрять того, чего они не смогут поддерживать за те же деньги в будущем. Проще просто найти новое место работы.

---

### По поводу фреймворков указанных в вопросе:

angular и laravel. Надо заметить что два этих фреймворка выполняют совершенно разные функции и реализованы на разных языках программирования.
Angular разработан исключительно для front-end,  в то время как Laravel разработан по большей части для backend разработки. У обоих есть множество конкурентов и это лишь капля в море. Их невозможно сравнивать друг с другом.

Laravel можно сравнивать с Symfony, CodeIgniter, Yii (1/2), Zend Framework, CakePHP, Phalcon,..etc. Его также можно сравнивать в той или иной степени с фреймворками разработанных на других языках программирования: Ruby-on-Rails(Ruby), Django(Python), etc.

Angular можно сравнивать с другими front-end фреймворками: React.JS, Backbone.js, Ember, Meteor, Knockout.js, Polymer.

Но каждое из этих сравнений будет достойно отдельного поста, по размеру не отличающегося от данного и оно будет субъективно(на вкус и цвет-товарищей нет), поэтому я решил уделить больше сравнению фреймворков с готовыми и кастомизируемыми решениями и общим вопросам.

Также хочу сказать что, фреймворки не ограничены вебом.

Android к примеру - это тоже фреймворк. Как и MFC и многое другое.

---

Наверное, я ответил на все Ваши вопросы. Если нужно что-то ещё - напишите в комментарии.

Comment: согласен на все 100

Comment: Господа, хоть отписывайте в комментарий, когда минус ставите.

Comment: Минус не мой, но обычно ответ на очень общий вопрос никому особенно не поможет. SO позиционируется как сайт ответов на конкретные вопросы, которые могут возникнуть еще у кого-то и в дальнейшем помогут решить проблему еще кому-нибудь. А тут автор задал вопрос из разряда «а давайте поговорим». Ваш ответ, на который вы потратили много времени, это не более чем *мнение*, пусть и подтвержденное рассуждениями.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, Вас понял. Спасибо за мнение!