# Какова актуальность разработки сайтов на чистом PHP и MySQL или Фреймворков перед WordPress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, база-данных, django

Какова актуальность разработки сайтов на чистом PHP и MySQL перед WordPress ?
Я уже знаком с азами web-прогроммирования и писал пару сайтов, сейчас хочу расширить свой кругозор(назовем это так), но мучает один вопрос, в чем актуальность разработки сайтов на php или даже, если взять фреймворк django перед CMS WoorPress,Joomla и т.д. Почему стоит разрабатывать самому, а не пользоваться готовым решением и чуть его подлатать ?

Задаю вопрос в связи с тем, что решаю на чем начать писать новый проект, где у кого какие плюсы, минусы.

Comment: Django, так-то, на Python, а не на PHP

Comment: Я понимаю, что Django фреймворк использующий язык Python

Comment: Ну все ведь зависит от задач. Если ваша задача уметь в программирование это однозначно framework. Если задача заработать денег сделав что то "по-быстрому" - это CMS . Почему не стоит писать на "чистом PHP" - потому что в этом нет совершенно никакого смысла в прикладном плане, исключительно в академическом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/702220/220220. Написано давно, и WP уже не на 25%, а на 37% сайтов.

Comment: Ты автомобиль тоже сам собираешь? А телевизор, стиральную машину, холодильник и тд? А ВП это даже не типовой автомобиль, а очень гибкий конструктор. Говоря по IT-шному - фреймворк, только не такой как все другие.

Comment: @SeVlad поддерживаю на все 100. Давно уже фреймворк, с 40+ API, что и не снилось многим другим "классическим" фреймворкам

Comment: @KAGGDesign когда я пару лет назад начал называть ВП фреймворком - меня чуть не порвали "классические фрейморколюбители" :) И с тех пор на форумах в срачах про ВП я всегда так выступаю - очень интересно наблюдать разрывы шаблонов некоторых кодеров :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сравнивать с детскими конструкторами:

**CMS** - это узкоспециализированный конструктор, в котором у вас есть готовый монолитный блок космического корабля. И есть разные фигурки, там, пушки, еще что-то. И вы можете эти фигурки пристраивать.

Если вам захочется пристроить что-то особенное, свое, вы не сможете это осуществить. Точнее, сможете, но придется, к примеру, взять нож и из пушки вырезать какого-нибудь своего коня. Затем вырезать в космическом корабле дырку под него.

**Фреймворк** - предлагает каркас, из которого можно сделать что угодно - и корабль, и самолет, и пирог для праздника. Вместе с каркасом - набор инструментов наподобие мелких деталей в лего. Из этих деталей Вы сможете сделать что угодно, хоть пушку, хоть коня.

В итоге все зависит от задачи: когда-то подойдет и CMS, когда-то лучше фреймворк. Если выбираете CMS - нужно заранее определиться с тем, что будет определенный функционал. Если в перспективе планируется расширять и усложнять проект - вы в любом случае упретесь в потолок возможностей CMS.

Подробнее вот тут человек много чего написал: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683328/вопрос-про-фреймворки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683328/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Answer (score 1):

Актуальность в том что популярен ВП. И это его ставит на уровень выше с написанным тобой или другими людьми фреймворками.
ВП позволяет зарабатывать тысячи и миллионы. Очередь к спецам выстраивается. Востребованность растет. Хороших спецов днем с огнем не сыскать. Так что сторонние фреймворки далеко позади.

Да и клиент тебе спасибо не скажет за то что ты, например, умер - а твой неизвестный фреймворк некому поддерживать и потом все равно переписывать на что-то другое.

Answer (score 0):

У любого приложения есть своя Архитектура. Вы можете разработать свою собственную используя почти любой язык программирования(на стороне сервера).

Что касается веб-разработки, то это направление не новое и наши предки уже набили много шишек пока научились пилить годные веб-приложения, хотя идеальной архитектуры до сих пор не найдено. Тем не менее, на ваш выбор существует много готовых решений, которые делают одно и то же но отличаются реализацией. Вы как разработчик можете согласиться с условиями игры например PHP фреймворка Laravel так как его структура вам по душе, а можете полюбить symfony, тут уместна поговорка "На вкус и цвет товарища нет".

Используя фреймворки вы пишете приложение "с нуля", но вам дают много готовых типовых решений которые вы можете применять как есть либо изменять до неузнаваемости, суть заключается в том, что работая с фреймворком вы будете обязаны соблюдать определённые правила. Таким образом любой программист знающий данный фреймворк сможет без труда присоединиться к разработки вашего приложения, так как документация по всем типовым решениям уже есть.

Что касается разработки на чистом PHP с какой нибудь СУБД, то идея хорошая. И этим стоит заняться если вы начинающий. Таким образом по мере написания кода вы увидите несовершенство той структуры которую создали по наитию, и будете искать различные упрощения и готовые решения в интернетах, таким образом вы сами придёте к какому нибудь популярному фреймворку и влюбитесь в него, так как он позволит вам делать то, что вы уже умеете сами, но в несколько раз быстрее. При написании приложения без фреймворка надо ещё помнить, что только вы знаете как эта хрень будет работать, а другому программисту придётся изучать ваш код, чтобы понять как программа работает. И ещё, нет смысла изучать фреймворк или пытаться его применить если не знаете языка на котором он написан.

Случай с CMS гараздо интересней. CMS это система управления контентом и по сути приложение за вас уже написано, а всё что вам требуется это дописать недостающие возможности и вобщем то всё. CMS готовый к употреблению продукт.

А теперь аналогия. Вы хотите сварить куриный суп:

1. Вы пишете сами на PHP (это как вырастить курицу, убить, ощипать, разделать итд. выкопать картошку, помыть, почистить итд.) затем ещё и суп готовить - долго, но зато своё родное!
2. Вы пишите с фреймворокм (это как купить курицу замороженную в магазине, купить остальные ингредиенты в магазине, всё что от вас нужно просто из них сварить суп) - быстро, единственное непонятно какого бренда брать мясо Laravel или Symfony, а может вообще вместо курицы взять другое мясо Django? Кароче есть можно, за качество ингредиентов ручается производитель.
3. Вы используете CMS - вы купили готовый суп, а дальше можете туда добавить соль если не хватает или  сухарики насыпать, может зелени добавить. Кароче у вас готовый продукт, но вы можете его модернизировать по вкусу!